# Javascript Variable Assignment of Object While Maintaing Reference

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

I have two variables referring to the same object so that objectA === objectB is true. I want to be able to assign {} to objectB and have objectA hold {} as well however whenever I do this I'm really just changing objectB's reference to wherever {} is (I think) so now objectA and objectB refer to different things. I have a way to do it, objectA = objectB = {}, but I don't like this because it requires a circular reference in my implementation. Is this possible or is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you want A and B to reference the same empty class? I can't see any reason for doing that.

Comment: Because I have a program with multiple states, each state represented by a different class. The states have a state manager which holds information pertaining to all of the states. objectA is in the state manager class and is passed to the state one class and stored at objectB (at which point it is undefined). I want to define objectB and have objectA be defined.

Comment: There is no way to have this happen automatically. As long as both variables reference the same object they can each add/change/remove properties of that object and each see the changes (since it's the same object), but you can't assign one to a new object and have the other "follow".

Comment: Okay thank you that's the answer I need then.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy constructor for copying value of one object to other and then objectA and objectB will not equal but they have same value in properties.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

`a = { foo:'Bar' }`

`b = Object.create(a)`
Create a new object that has the object `a` as prototype.

`a == b` is false

`b.foo` is `"bar"`

---

Setting a property in `a` will make it available in `b` too through the prototype chain.

`a.foo = "qux"`

`b.foo` is `"qux"` too.

---

It doesn't work the other way around:

`b.other = 'a'`

`a.other` is `undefined`.

---

Note that `Object.create` is part of ECMA Script 5, and need to check if your target browsers support it: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.create

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm really trying to make it so a and b both refer to the same object and both are empty objects.

The reason is so I can update one of the objects from one class and have it update in another class without me having to have a reference to that class from the first one.

Perhaps it's stupid of me to be passing around undefined objects at all but I was curious to see if it were possible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that without extra clutter, you'd need a variable that can refer to another variable.  That isn't possible in JavaScript -- variables and properties refer only to *values*, and are passed around strictly by value.  That means that the reference in A is a *copy* of the one in B, and assigning a new reference to one can not affect the other directly.

You could achieve a similar effect, though, by having A and B point at the same (possibly empty) object, and then modifying a property of that object.  Since both variables refer to the same object, the property change will appear in both places.  It's a little clumsier than built-in C++-style reference variables, but it works if both sides know the rules.

(The big difference is, this setup won't let you arbitrarily set variables that weren't shared this way.  But frankly, i'd consider that a *good* thing.)

Comment: I've been reading a lot about the passing reference by copy concept but I'm not sure I completely understand. If I have a constructor like function FirstContainer(inputHandler){this.inputHandler = inputHandler; this.otherContainer = new OtherContainer(inputHandler);} Does this mean that the inputHandler in OtherContainer refers to the same inputHandler in FirstContainer or are they separate inputHandlers?

It seems confusing to me because if I copy the reference shouldn't that mean they point to the same place?

Comment: @user3015797: All three `inputHandler`s' values refer to the same object, yes. But they are not related in any other way. Lemme try to clarify... Behind all the pageantry and mystery, a reference is just a number that identifies a particular object. Like any other number in JavaScript, every time you store it, or pass it to a function, you create a copy. Every copy is equal in every meaningful way.  But like real-world copies, *each copy exists independently* -- if you destroy your own copy of the number, or scribble a new number over top of it, you haven't changed any other copy but yours.